# Guess four functions given their boundary derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

For some reason I am loking for four functions $a(x,y),b(x,y),c(x,y),u(x,y)$

Where $a+b$ is harmonic i.e.

$$\frac{\partial^2 (a+b)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 (a+b)}{\partial y^2}=0$$

and

$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial c}{\partial y} = A$$

$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = B$$

where $A$ and $B$ are some given constants.

And most importantly

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,y)+a(0,y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(1,y)+a(1,y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y)+c(0,y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,y)+c(1,y)=0$$

These functions can be arbitrary but the simpler the better.

I would be very glad if you have any suggestions for a solution.

Thank you.

Note that I am loking for some particular solution. This problem arised when I computed some partial differential equation.

**EDIT:**

That means it will be for example sufficient for me to tell me function *u(x,y)* which satisfies these boundary conditions: (I have chosen $a=Ax$,$b=By$).

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(1,y)=-A$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,y)=0$$

Is there such $u(x,y)$?

Comment: Is there not a typo in your system of equations : $$\frac{\partial^2 (a+b)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 (a+b)}{\partial y^2}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial c}{\partial y} = A$$
$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = B$$ since no $u$ appears into them ?

Comment: There are 4 unknowns and only 3 equations. You need one more.

Comment: It'd also help it you provide the full context, i.e. what's the original PDE?

Comment: There is not a typo. The context is, you have some boundary conditions for some PDE but they are not vanishing, so the proper way how to make them vanish is to find appropriate polynomial to subtract, however, I was unsuccessful to find such. You don't need more equation, this problem is as it is. Moreover I wrote in the last paragraph that **any** solution for me will be the solution. Any particular solution.

Comment: That's not enough context. What is "some PDE"? Please provide the full PDE, or we can't go anywhere.